# Make TypeScript aware of loaded object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to do some work with Google Analytics.  The google js that you load adds a `gapi` variable to the `window` dom object.

When coding the TypeScript isn't complaining about the fact that `gapi` doesn't exist on `window` object.

I'm trying to detect if the `gapi` file is loaded and if not then load it dynamically from my script.

GAPI doesn't have a Type Definition that I can find so I'm trying to figure out how to check that it's loaded into the DOM.  I've been able to check it's (non-) existence through the console on Chrome and through jQuery so either is an option.  Just can't figure out how to do this in TypeScript since it doesn't know about `gapi` at all.

If you haven't used the Google Analytics js library.  It returns both a `window.gapi` and a `gapi` ref for you to use in `code`/`DOM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make TypeScript aware of the addition you would use:

```
interface Window {
    gapi: any;
}
```

Or the shorter:

```
declare var gapi: any;
```

You could optionally flesh out the definition.

This should then allow you to use gapi, including in your detection script:

```
if (typeof gapi === 'undefined') ...
```

Comment: `declare var gapi: any;` was what I was looking for.

Comment: `declare var gapi: any;` is not working for mobile iOS Safari on iOS 15. Do you know what could we do in 2021?